# Rails 4 routing of partial tacks on to existing path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes, partial, cascadingdropdown

I am new to writing rails applications.  I am using Rails 4.2.0 with Ruby 2.0.0p598.

I have modified the cascading select implementation found [here](https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/) and used it to create new Products (has model and main controller) linked to Productgroups and Productsubgroups (both have their models, but no controllers) as the cascade levels.  The implementation employs some javascript which upon a change to the first dropdown select, the second dropdown is cleared of data, and then an AJAX call is made to a specific URL to update the  tags for the productsubgroups dropdown using a partial (_productsubgroup.html.erb).

To do this, the following route set up in routes.rb

get     '/update_productsubgroups' => 'products#update_productsubgroups'

so that i can map to the appropriate controller and action.  This is all quite fine.  I can see the AJAX request in the development.log as where it is querying the database for productgroup #2 (ignore the trailing "&_1422575676984"):

```
Started GET "/products/update_productsubgroups?productgroup_id=2&_=1422575676984"
```

The problem, occurs when I use the same content from new.html.erb within the context of editing a product in edit.html.erb.  Based on the fact that the routes.rb uses the "resouces :products" directive, I end up with a url for editing products in the form /product/:id/edit (e.g. /product/2/edit to edit the product with ID 2).  When I try to use my cascading dropdowns, everytime I make a change to the first selection, I don't get a change in the second dropdown.  I can see the request going to the development.log file as:

```
Started GET "/products/1/update_productsubgroups?productgroup_id=2&_=1422578544393"
```

and the error that comes up immediately after the request is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/products/1/update_productsubgroups"):
```

**Q1** - Why does the partial just tack on to the existing URL rather than simply make a pure request to /products/update_productsubgroups as is the case when I create a product from the product controller's 'new' action?

**Q2** - Is there any way for me to create a rule in the routes.rb to map things correctly?

**Q3** - When I try to create a new route as

```
get '/products/:id/update_productsubgroups', as 'products#update_productsubgroups'
```

I get an error in the webserver log as:

```
ArgumentError ('products/:id' is not a supported controller name
```

I have dug around and I am not certain how to interpret this.  Can anyone help explain this so that the last couple of hours can prove a useful learning experience?  Unfortunately, most pages either discuss routing for Rails 3 or just refer to the 'Routing from the outside in' page and that seems to confuse me even more because I'm specifying things as expected, namely `:controller/:id/:action.`

Answer (score 0):

DOH!

I had a relative path specified for my AJAX call!  I looked everywhere except the coffeescript file.

```
$.ajax 'update_productsubgroups',
```

should be

```
$.ajax '/update_productsubgroups',
```